# php with SQL query

Tags: php, sql

i have a problem with php in the following:

```
$sql = 'SELECT name FROM chiled WHERE `im` LIKE $id ';
$query = mysql_query( $sql );
$a=mysql_fetch_row($query);
echo $a[0];
```

there is error in `mysql_fetch_row($query);`
but if i do the following :

```
$sql = 'SELECT name FROM chiled WHERE `im` LIKE 1111 ';
$query = mysql_query( $sql );
$a=mysql_fetch_row($query);
echo $a[0];
```

it is working and prints the name 
can you please tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Single quotes in PHP doesn't evaluate embedded variables - you need to use double quotes to do that. (See the "Single quoted" section of the PHP [Strings manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) for more info..)

i.e.:  `$sql = "SELECT name FROM chiled WHERE 'im' LIKE $id "`;

Or better still...

```
$sql = 'SELECT name FROM chiled WHERE im="' . mysql_real_escape_string($id) . '"';
```

(As you're not using the `%` in your like, you're presumably not attempting to do any form of pattern matching.)

Additionally, I'd recommend a read of the existing [Best way to stop SQL Injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php) question/answers.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to be using `LIKE`? It looks more to me like you want to see if `im = $id`. Also, make sure you're escaping your variables before using them in the query.

**Edit**
If you DO want to us LIKE, you probably want something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM chiled WHERE `im` LIKE '%$id%' ";
```

which will find anywhere that the string `$id` is found in the `im` column.

Comment: No, he don't want to use like

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the variable after `LIKE`, like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM chiled WHERE im LIKE '$id'";
$query = mysql_query($sql); 
$a = mysql_fetch_row($query); 
echo $a[0]; 
// ....
```

Beside, you are using single quotes, Therefore, `$id` is not replaced for its value. Your query look like this:
`SELECT name FROM chiled WHERE im LIKE $id;`

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM chiled WHERE `im` LIKE '$id' ";
```

change to double quotes - http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php